# Kusto Query: filter values of nested JSON Array

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

```
let myTable = datatable(str: string, record: dynamic) [
    "someText", dynamic([{"upperBound": 98, "lowerBound": 4, "values": [1,4,5,98,99] }])
];
```

I want to transform the content of the table by filtering the **"values"** array so it contains only values which are lesser than the lower bound or greater than the upper bound. So the result should look like this:

```
let myTable = datatable(str: string, record: dynamic) [
    "someText", dynamic([{"upperBound": 98, "lowerBound": 4, "values": [1,99] }])
];
```

There are **array_sort** functions but I could not find an **array_filter** or something equivalent. I'd appreciate if someone could point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

it would be much more efficient to emit valid records by the origin component than to have to do this type of manipulation after the fact.

that said, you could use the `mv-apply` function to achieve this (if you're ok with the inherent inefficiency)

```
datatable(str: string, record: dynamic) [
    "someText", dynamic([{"upperBound": 98, "lowerBound": 4, "values": [1,4,5,98,99] }]),
    "someText2", dynamic([{"upperBound": 90, "lowerBound": 10, "values": [7,46,85,8,79,95,19,91] }])
]
| mv-apply r = record on (
    extend upperBound = tolong(r.upperBound), lowerBound = tolong(r.lowerBound)
    | mv-apply v = r.values on (
        where v < lowerBound or v > upperBound
        | summarize values = make_list(v)
    )
    | project record = bag_merge(bag_remove_keys(r, pack_array("values")), bag_pack("values", values))
)
```

| str | record |
| --- | --- |
| someText | { "upperBound": 98, "lowerBound": 4, "values": [ 1, 99 ] } |
| someText2 | { "upperBound": 90, "lowerBound": 10, "values": [ 7, 8, 95, 91 ] } |